# « Messieurs dames » est « très vulgaire » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, formulation, salutations, vulgarité

Je lisais le passage ci-dessous de « La Nausée » et j'ai remarqué que « Messieurs dames » était souligné, ce qui veut dire qu'il y a une note sur cette phrase à la fin du livre (il me semble que c'est une édition étudiante ou quelque chose du genre) :

> Un homme est entré, frileusement.
>
> « Messieurs dames, bonjour »
>
> Il s'assied, sans quitter son pardessus verdi. Il frotte l'une contre
> l'autre ses longues mains en enchevetrant ses doigts

Le note dit :

> **Messieurs dames.** Formule de « politesse » très vulgaire.

Je me demande donc en quoi c'est vulgaire, voire *très* vulgaire ? Il me semble pas très loin de « Mesdames, Messieurs », ce qui est quelque chose que j'entends régulièrement. S'agit-il du deuxième degré peut-être ?

NB: Merci pour les commentaires. Bien qu'ils m'aide à mieux comprendre, je veux préciser que je m'intéresse plutôt à si/pourquoi/en quoi cette phrase est « très vulgaire ».

Comment: « très vulgaire » me semble grandement exagéré. Je dirais familier, populaire peut-être désuet en 2023. Voir [TLI](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/messieurs-dames#), [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/messieurs-dames), [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/messieurs/50782).

Comment: Le sens de *vulgaire* a évolué et s'est spécialisé. Aujourd'hui, *Messieurs dames* est simplement un peu familier alors que *M'sieurs-dames* et lui plus relâché et familier. Le contexte joue beaucoup aussi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ca dépend, du contexte, de la personne qui le dit... L'expression est un peu "abrégée" ce qui lui donne un caractère sans doute assez "populaire". Comme si l'interlocuteur prononçait cette phrase sans vraiment y mettre beaucoup de respect. Quand j'entends cette phrase, j'imagine un personnage un peu gouaille qui entre dans un bar avec une casquette sur la tête, dans les années cinquante ou même avant, et qui lance cette salutation pour annoncer son arrivée plus que pour vraiment saluer les autres clients. Donc, contexte "populaire" et époque passée.

Mais "très vulgaire" est peut-être aller trop loin. "*Mesdames, Messieurs*" en prenant le temps de ne rien abréger, serait peut-être plus formel et respectueux, et tout à fait acceptable de nos jours.

Comment: Super merci @Frank - c'est exactement ce que je cherchais.